# Test my mouse online

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, hardware-failure

Though this question might look like a one man's issue, link to such a utility could be useful to many others.

I have a Microsoft Optical mouse which occasionally behaves weird. It takes double clicks for a single click, opens a single file twice or thrice and so on. I work on Ubuntu operating system and I am not aware of any tool/website which can let me test my mouse. I am unsure if the same behavior can be seen on a Windows PC. Prior to taking it for a warranty replacement I wish to test it and make sure.

Comment: Sounds like the button is wearing out. My current mouse is doing the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but in X11 you can use [xev](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xev.1.html) to receive events and output them to console, might help somewhat in your debugging efforts.

It is also possibly [available](http://cygwin.com/packages/xev/) under [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) in Windows - haven't tested it though